# How I can check for identity column from T4 template(tt) file?

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I want to add following attribute in my class property if **db column is Primary key and not identity**
consider following code

```
[Key, Column(Order =  0), DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )]
public virtual int TypeId
{ get; set; }
```

I have used following code to check for primary key

```
bool isPrimaryKey = ef.IsKey(edmProperty);
#>
<#
if (isPrimaryKey)
{
#>
[Key]
<#
}
#>
```

Now i need some code to check is Column is identity ? If not then i will add 
following attribute 
**DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )** from my T4 template code.
I am using [EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) for generating my poco classes. Now i want to modify it.
Now how i can do this?
Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a naming convention of tblWidget and WidgetId for the primary key then can you use that to detect that it is the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for making replay. I can identify primary key easily. I just need to identify is column "Idendity" (AutoIncrement)? Naming convention is not possible because i am working Brown Field project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public const string annotationNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation";

MetadataProperty storeGeneratedPatternProperty = null;
edmProperty.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue(annotationNamespace + ":StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out storeGeneratedPatternProperty);
bool IsIdentity = storeGeneratedPatternProperty != null && storeGeneratedPatternProperty.Value.ToString() == "Identity";
```

Comment: Trying to get your snippet above to work in my custom t4 scaffolding...  I'm looking at adding a function to CustomTemplates/MvcView/ModelMetadataFunctions.cs.include.t4. Error messages have informed me that the .MetadataProperties is in a different namespace, so, I added System.Data.Metadata.Edm to the 'using' file, but, am not sure where to go from there - I'm starting with an instance of modelProperty  - a type of PropertyMetadata, but, I think your edmProperty must be something else

Comment: edmXXX is about EntityFramework and from your comment I don't quite understand how your case (which is about MVC view scaffolding I believe) relates to it. You have to have edm metadata on input in my example

Comment: you are correct. I finally figured out my issue.  As you said, I was doing some MVC scaffolding and basically barking up the wrong tree by posting a comment to this thread. Should we clean up our comments and just delete them out?

Comment: Up to you. I don't see anything wrong about either keeping them or deleting them